# Pass a View from One controller to Other Controller iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have  tableView in first controller and i am making it with tableviewcells defined in xib. Now when i click on one tableviewcell i need to open a present view controller and pass on the View of tableviewcell to second view controller.

I am using a init method in second view controller and passed the cell.contentView of 1st VC to 2nd VC.

It is working fine tableviewcell content view is getting shown on the 2ND VC first table section but when i press close to the 2nd VC .The TableViewCell content view disappears from first VC.

I am not able to so. I have seen on net they are saying register XIB again on 2nd VC , or use archive and unarchive but these are time consuming operations and i just want to pass a tableviewcell content view to 2nd vc and when i close 1st VC i want it back there.

Any help would be appreciated.

> View is the cell.contentView of the pressed tableview cell

```
self.superViewCell = View;

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     HVAPParentTableViewCell * cell = [[HVAPParentTableViewCell alloc] init];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:self.superViewCell];
     return cell;

      }
```

Comment: No no no!!!! Don't do this!!! Rethink your design pattern!

Comment: This seems a rather strange arquitechture. What I'd advise would be: 1- If you need an image/representation of the view, you should take a screenshot and pass it around. 2 - If you need the functionality from that view, you would pass a variable (for example a Dictionary) with the information you need and build the view on the next View Controller. You shouldn't however, pass the content view.

Comment: How should i take screenshot and pass it around ? Its a small view which i need in 2nd vc

Comment: Wow..thats good ... i am asking a question which i think is genuine and you guys are downvoting.. Let me know why ?

Answer (score 1):

The cell is probably missing in the *1st* view controller because you removed its `contentView` and passed over to the *2nd* view controller. This is clearly an anti-pattern you probably don't want to use. You may want to pass over to the *2nd* view controller cell's "state" rather than its `contentView` though, and initialise a new cell with the same cell data.

Having little knowledge about what you're actually trying to achieve, my general advice would be to register the *2nd* view controller's table view with the same xibs and cell identifiers as in the *1st* view controller. Now you can pass over only the selected cell's identifier (so that you know which one to use when dequeueing in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for the passed-over cell) and cell's data. Then you can initialise the same cell in *2nd* view controller with cell's data from *1st* view controller.

Comment: I know this thing but i want to do it a different way. This is the usual way i do this. but thanks

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta Well if you're 100% sure you want to do it this way, you may need to either: 
**a)** pass the cell's view back to view controller 1 and manually stick it back in the original cell; 
**b)** call `reloadData` on the 1st view controller's table to re-create the cell; 
**c)** obtain a "deep copy" of the view before passing it over to view controller 2 via `NSKeyedArchiver`, so that the old one remains in place.